# How do I restrict users from entering redundant data in C++ program?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program to read a number of student records.

The data entered should be unique.

How do I do this?

Comment: Use a database. After user enters a record try to read it by what is unique. If it exists show a message. If not write to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use std::map with key -> primary key, value instance of your student class, but for good use some kind of database which will handle it for you.

Comment: Hi i'm not yet an professional programmer. I'm an Information Science student and it's an assignment from my lecturer. he is explicitly mentioned we shouldn't use any database application.

Comment: then read your objects to the map and write the map to the file, the std::map will make care about your keys, so there are the restriction that you can't insert the same key twice in the std::map.

Answer (score 0):

Is the following any good?:

```
bool appendUserRecord( int input, std::vector<int>& records )
{
    for ( std::vector<int>::iterator _it = records.begin(); 
                                     _it < records.end(); ++_it )
    {
        if ( *_it == input )
            return false;
    }
    records.push_back( input );
    return true;
}
```

This function will return true when a unique 'record' is added, otherwise false if it already exists. Only minor modification is required to implement this with a record class/struct rather than an integer.

As for storing the data in a file, you simply need to open a file stream and use a for loop to pass all the records to it in a serialised form. Use a while loop (while not end of file) to retrieve the data.